# Way to delete row from list if criteria met

Tags: c#

i am running two lists through a fuzzy matching program and want to be able to remove that row from the list if a match occurs but am having problems doing so. here is my code

```
 foreach (var name in list)
            {
                foreach (var stepone in Step1)
                {
                    if (FuzzyMatching(name.Full(), stepone.Full()) >= 90)
                    {
                        csvcontent.AppendLine(name.Full());
                        //find a way to delete list record out of list
                        //list.Remove(name);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: You can't delete an item from a collection that you are for-eaching over.

Answer (score 1):

you can mark in another list all the items to delete.
When the loop is finished you can delete all the items in the new created list from that list.
With LINQ is simply:

```
list1 = list1.Where(x => !itemToDeleteList.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove an item from a list using a ForEach loop. In this case you should use a for loop.

```
var list = new List<string>();

list.Add("a");
list.Add("b");
list.Add("c");
list.Add("d");

for(int i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
{
    if(list[i].Contains("a"))
    {
        list.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Your results list will be:

```
b 
c 
d
```

Leaving the above for reference, but to @LarsTech comment below, list.RemoveAt breaks the loop so it will only remove 1 item. If you are wanting to remove multiple items, Alex's other answer with the Linq would be the cleanest way to remove it.

If you don't want to create a second list to house the items to be deleted, you can also do the below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count(); i++)
{
    if (list[i].Contains("a"))
    {
        list = list.Where(x => !x.Contains("a")).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try testing your code with `if (list[i].Contains("a") | list[i].Contains("b"))`

Answer (score 0):

When you loop over a list with `foreach` and try to remove an item, you will get a runtime InvalidOperationException:

> Collection was modified, enumeration operation may not execute

So you can use a `for` loop, which can handle modifications to the list. However, when you delete an item, all higher indexes will shift down. This will mean you skip an item.

The solution is to iterate in reverse order:

```
var list = new List<string>();

list.Add("a");
list.Add("b");
list.Add("b");
list.Add("c");
list.Add("d");

for (int i = list.Count()-1; i>=0; i--)
{
    if (list[i].Contains("b"))
    {
        list.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
// result: a, c, d
```

- you have to start at "count - 1", because that is the highest actual index
- the last index to use is 0 (the start of the list)
- and decrease the index after every iteration